# Integral $\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1 r^3 \sqrt{1/r^{2} -1}dr$

Tags: integration

I have integral $\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1 r^3 \sqrt{\frac{1}{r^2}-1}dr$.

I calculated:
$$
\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1 r^3 \sqrt{\frac{1}{r^2}-1}dr= \int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1 r^3 \sqrt{\frac{1-r^2}{r^2}}dr=\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1 r^2\sqrt{1-r^2} dr.
$$
But then I dont know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r=\sin{\theta}$:
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2{\theta}\cos^2{\theta} \; d\theta\overset{1}{=}\frac{1}{4} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2{2\theta} \; d\theta\overset{2}{=}\frac{1}{8} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\cos{4\theta}) \; d\theta=\left(\frac{1}{8} \theta-\frac{1}{32}\sin{4\theta}\right) \bigg \rvert_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{32}}$$

$1$:  Sine double angle ($2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}=\sin{2\theta}$)

$2$: Power reducing identity for sine ($\sin^2{\theta}=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\cos{2\theta}\right)$)